# What does "prime" mean in this context?

Tags: terminology, hash, hash-tables

In a lecture video the instructor introduced the quadratic probing method for hash tables. The formula he gave was the following:

$h(k,i) = (h'(k) + c_1 + c_2i^2)$ $\% M$

where $h'$ was h "prime". So, what I am supposed to conclude for $h'(k)$ to be? Is it any different from the value I get by computing $h(k)$

Comment: It has no particular significance. It could have been any other symbol instead of $h’$. It’s different from $h$, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h'(k)$ is the value returned by the original unmodified hash function when applied to the element $k$. If the $h(k)$ slot is not free then $h(k,i)$ for $i=0,1,2,\dots$ gives a sequence of modified hash values which can be tried in turn until a free slot is found.